# Usage of Base64 encoding

Tags: base64

I write server that sends two types of messages: plain message (without encoding) and encrypted message (AES encryption). The transport is UDP. The message content is fixed-length header (2 bytes) and body (JSON string). The question: should I encode these messages using Base64 encoding?  If so, what is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`base64`encoding has one reason to exist (and this one only): Make something, that is **not** safe for handling and/or transport in a text-based system (such as E-Mail, classic `C` strings) safe to do so.

UDP definitly has no such limit, so it depends on whether any other part of your application does. If not, I recommend you use the raw data.

Answer (score 1):

base64 was meant to encode binary data (which is very compact) into group of 64 symbols in the ASCII table (which is less compact). base64 is very good for storing binary data inside text files, things like storing image data inside HTML document etc. I don't see any reason to use it in your case

Comment: Thanks  for quick  and understandable answers.